# How many times drupal calls hook_node_presave for a node?

Tags: hooks

During debugging my code I noticed that `hook_node_presave()` is called 3 times when I edit a node. Why?

I use the following code to count how many times the function is called:

```
function mymodule_node_presave($node) {
  static $counter = 0;

  // Some code...

  $counter++;
  watchdog('mymodule', "hook has been called $counter");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once.

If it's called multiple times then you your node is saved multiple times.

This might be because you have some rules or other code that e.g. resaves the node in a hook_node_insert()/update().

To find out what and where, enable devel.module if you haven't already and add a `ddebug_backtrace()` call to your hook. That will give you the backtrace on how your function was called and you can identify who is calling node_save().

Comment: I added `ddebug_backtrace()` to mymodule_node_presave() . It shows that only this hook(mymodule_node_presave) is called 3 times.

Comment: Yes, and each of the output elements is a expandable krumo thingy that shows the full backtrace of each call. Click on it and post it here, if necessary.

Comment: @Berdir `OT` : It happens for init hook as well when debugging but if i print any text it prints only once , how can this be explained